# Changing default locations for svelte template

Tags: templates, default, svelte-3

After having copied the [svelte template](https://github.com/sveltejs/template) on my local machine, I need `npm install` to create `public` and `src` folders to different locations than the default ones. Specifically, if I run `npm install` from my `/projects/sveltetemplate` folder, I'd like to have `public` and `src` created as subfolders in `/projects/appdev` .
 I may also need to use a different name for `public` folder.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just change the folders location and then update the file `rollup.config.js` to use those new locations.

Comment: Although it doesn't answer the question per se (it implies post-install actions) it solves the problem. Editing the rollup config file was easy.